# Java crashes with fatal error

Tags: java, crash, openjdk

I'm trying to get [SweetHome3D](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/sweethome3d) to work on Lubuntu 16.04, but it crashes immediately after starting. I get the following error message:

```
> sweethome3d
Java 3D: implicit antialiasing enabled
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f2f13517823, pid=6350, tid=139841325328128
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_91-b14) (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.91-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [swrast_dri.so+0x256823]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid6350.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

I tried to use the standalone version from http://www.sweethome3d.com/download.jsp, but it produces the same error:

```
> bash SweetHome3D 
Java 3D: implicit antialiasing enabled
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f673f416823, pid=4519, tid=140081432098560
#
# JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.45-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [swrast_dri.so+0x256823]  __driDriverGetExtensions_virtio_gpu+0x1bad73
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/konstantin/ind/Software/SweetHome3D/SweetHome3D-5.2/hs_err_pid4519.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Note the two different versions used – locally installed is OpenJDK 8.0_91-b14, the second try used the included (Oracle) Java 6.0_45-b06, the issue remains the same for both versions. The error log of the first try can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/MXh4ugHz), the one of the second try [here](http://pastebin.com/jTfAaegQ).

What can I try to get it working?

Comment: Note: the last line (`Abgebrochen …`) translated becomes `Aborted (written dump)`

Comment: It's just an 'if' but can you select the `Memtest86+` option at the boot menu and post the results? It basically checks your RAM for defects, which I suspect to be the cause.

Comment: I tried it in a virtual machine with a vanilla Lubuntu 16.04 32bit installation, both ways it gave *exactly* the same results. Wouldn't my system behave unusual if my RAM would be the problem? I don't experience any of the problems I'd expect to have… Of course I will test it anyway, but this has to be later.

Comment: Yes, just thought It'd be better to rule out the rare cause first, as it will save us a lot of wasted time if it turns out to be bad RAM.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju I finally did the test, and it didn't report any errors. Any other idea?

Comment: Seems to be a very specific problem, try reporting to the developers (http://www.sweethome3d.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as I can't reproduce the problem myself any more.

Comment: @dessert Does this remain non-reproducible? Had the close votes aged away, when you had tried to close it before? Is there any reason it shouldn't be closed now?

Comment: @EliahKagan It remains non-repro, my CV aged away and I see no reason not to close it now.

Comment: Closing your own question as Non-Repro!  +1